# How to display special price products in Sale category

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4

> How to display special price products in Sale category by default

Not like selecting products while creating categories or
 selecting category while adding products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using event > observer. 
Using **catalog_product_prepare_save** event of admin we can able to do this possible.

```
           <adminhtml>
             <events>
                <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    <observers>
                        <Modulename>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>Modulename/observer</class>
                            <method>onProductPrepareSave</method> 
                        </Modulename>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_prepare_save>
           </events>    
        </adminhtml>
```

Use below function in your module observer

```
class MyCompany_Modulename_Model_Adminhtml_Observer
{
  /**
    * Assign category 'sale' when product having sale price
    * 
    * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
    */
    public function onProductPrepareSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();     
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();     
        $postData = $request->getPost();        
        $categoryIds = array();
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if(isset($postData['product']['special_price'])) {
            if(!in_array('ID of Sale Cat',$categoryIds)) {
                $saleCatId = array('ID of Sale Cat');
                $updateCatIds = array_merge($categoryIds,$saleCatId);
                $product->setCategoryIds($updateCatIds);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Replace 'Modulename' with your module. Change 'ID of Sale Cat' with your 'Sale' category id.

I hope above code will help you.